# Simultaneously filter and merge pcap files

Tags: linux, packet-capture

Has anyone written a utility that *simultaneously* filters and merges many `pcap`-format packet capture files?  `tshark` and `tcpdump` filter but don't merge, `mergecap` merges but doesn't filter.  I am trying to filter down 64GB of captures (compressed!) into one much smaller file, and it would be nice if I didn't need *another* several GB of scratch space and two steps, both of them slow.

The utility *must* run on Linux and ideally would already be packaged in Debian.  Ability to read gzipped trace files is highly desirable.  Being fast is also highly desirable (`tshark` takes ten to thirty minutes to process *one* of the input files; there are 120 of them).  I can live with being limited to `libpcap`'s filter syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging through the reverse dependencies of libpcap in Debian found me [tracesplit](http://wand.net.nz/trac/libtrace/wiki/TraceSplit) (one of the command line utilities bundled with [libtrace](http://research.wand.net.nz/software/libtrace.php)) which does my simultaneous filter and merge, and can process the full data set in 20 minutes, which is probably as good as I'm getting.  It's a little weird that you use the *split* tool to *merge* with filtration, but whatever.